# How to represent NA in rJava

Tags: java, r, scala, rjava

I have a scala program that produces some time series data to be used in R. The data values are Doubles with some missing values but I don't know how I should represent these NA values in my scala program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `org.rosuda.REngine.REXPDouble.NA` to indicate to R that there is missing data.  It is a type of `Double.NaN`, but different than the one that Java normally uses (so you have to specify it).  You can use `org.rosuda.REngine.REXPDouble.isNA` to verify whether a `NaN` is R's missing-data NaN or an ordinary one.

For what it's worth, the value presently seems to be `0x7ff00000000007a2L`, which you can put into a double yourself like so: `java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff00000000007a2L)`.  Probably safer to just use `REXPDouble.NA`, though.

Comment: Double.NaN worked for me. Don't know what the org.rosuda package is?

Comment: I guess the conversion happens automatically in rJava.  I'd imagined you were using JRI also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type Option[A]. See for example this article: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html